# How to get list of all the data services added to flash builder at run time

Tags: android, web-services, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I was looking for a way to get the list of all my data services names  I added in flash builder at run time in actioscript. Like I have got 20 services on .net side and I generated their proxy classes in flash builder. Flash builder has generate service for each on them under service directory and appropriate proxies under value objects. Now I want to get the list of all the classes and service to do some stuff on it. I saw some posts SO but non of them was useful.

```
for each(var servicename:String in services)
            {//do my stuff here}
```

Comment: When you generate the proxy classes, you may generate a xml file to save the classes,then you can read the xml file to get the list of classes?

Comment: I did a work around to it. since I have the list of

Comment: I did a work around to it.                                           var _ClassInAction:Class =  getDefinitionByName("valueObjects."+ srvs +"") as Class;
 var Action:* = new _ClassInAction(); the variable srvs is the public name I just removed for some trailing texts and got it working using GetDefinitionByName.